# Cannot change color of the text using if condition Swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Below is my code. I'm trying to change the color of the text inside tableViewCell by using `if` condition that if the string contains `-` sign then it should go red or else green but it turns out all the strings go green.

```
cell.percentLabel.text = PercentChange[indexPath.row]

for i in PercentChange{
    if (i.range(of: "-") != nil) {
        cell.percentLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
   } else {
        cell.percentLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reload table view to update inside cell content.

Comment: What method is this code in? Provide some context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your posted code is in your `cellForRowAt` method, you should not be looping through all of the `PercentChange` values.

As written, you set the color of every cell based on the last value in `PercentChange`.

You should only be looking at the value specific to the given row.

```
let change = PercentChange[indexPath.row]
cell.percentLabel.text = change
cell.percentLabel.textColor = change.range(of: "-") != nil ? .red : .green
```